# Oracle: Multiple joins

Tags: sql, oracle, join

can anybody explain how this multiple joins works? Primary Key of A goes to Table B as foreign key while Primary key of B goes to C as foreign key. Thanks in advance.

```
Table A         TABLE B (has fk of A)               TBALE C (HAS FK OF B)
aid  aname      bid bname afk                       cid  cname bfk
 1   a           1   b      1                       1     c     1
 2  a2           2   b2     2                       2     c2     1

select a.aname , b.bname , c.cname from A a
left join B b
on a.aid = b.afk
left  join C c 
on c.bfk = b.bid;
```

Answer (score 1):

You will end up with the following result set:

```
a   b   c
a   b   c2
a2  b2  Null
```

You have no entry for the cname in the third record because there is no record in table c that has a bfk of 2.